# I got stuck on following c programming, did not concept of code

Tags: c

```
# define swap(a,b) temp=a; a=b; b=temp;    
main( )    
{    
    int i, j, temp;    
    i=5;    
    j=10;    
    temp=0;
    if( i > j)
        swap( i, j );
    printf( "%d %d %d", i, j, temp);
}
```

After executing above code, i am getting unexpected output, i am not getting the exact logic behind this.so guys please help me out.

Output of above code:

```
10 0 0
```

Comment: Tip: `int main()`, `return 0`, please stick to the basics.

Comment: @SouravGhosh In hosted environment it should be `int main(void)`, see N1570 5.1.2.2.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The macro `swap` is not a C function, instead the preprocessor inserts the macro *as is* in the place of the macro invocation, so the code looks like this:

```
if( i > j)
temp=i; i=j; j=temp;;
```

And after reformatting the code is

```
if( i > j)
    temp=i;
i=j;
j=temp;
;
```

Only the assignment to `temp` is done if the condition is true, the other two assignments are *always* done *unconditionally*.

This can be solved in two ways: Put the macro invocation inside a statement block:

```
if( i > j)
{
    swap( i, j );
}
```

*Or* make the macro body a block:

```
#define swap(a,b) do { temp=(a); (a)=(b); (b)=temp; } while (0)
```

The convention to put multi-statement macros inside a `do { ... } while (0)` statement is because otherwise you get an empty statement (like you do now, see above), which can cause problems when expanding the macro as part of e.g. an `if else` statement.

Comment: Kudos for not ignoring `j=temp;;`. :-)

Comment: actually the do { } while(0) is not required here; for multi-line/multi-instruction macros you simply use brackets {}  and it will be expanded in a code block

Comment: @Pandrei : but then you can't put a semicolon after the call, which is awkward.

Comment: @Quentin acutualy you can { instruction1; instruction2;}; is valid, compilable, executable code.

Comment: @Pandrei not in the case of `if(true) macro(); else {}`.

Comment: @Quentin fair point...but that's one reason why a inline function is better than a macro; but that's a different story.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( i > j)
{
  swap( i, j );
}
```

If your requirement is to swap `i` and `j` if `i>j` then do it as shown in the above code. Not a good idea to use macro here

```
void func(int *i,int *j)
{
   int t;
   t = *i;
   *i = *j;
   *j = t;
}
```

and call

```
if(i>j)
func(&i,&j);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your macro with a do ... while(0), like this:

```
#define swap(a,b) do { temp=a; a=b; b=temp;  } while(0)
```

Thus, the "if" will have an effect on the whole macro.

Comment: preferably without the final semicolon

Comment: You can even declare `temp` in the block limiting it's scope `do { int tem=(a); (a)=(b); (b)=temp; } while(0)`  Even in that case you'll have problems if you use something like `swap(a++, b);`.  There are strong reasons to switch to the inline function, as suggested in other comment.

Answer (score 0):

Only the first statement of the macro (i.e. `temp=a;`) is inside the `if(i > j)` condition. That's why you don'get what you expect.

You should surround any multi-statement macro with {} to avoid this problem.

```
#define swap(a,b) {temp=a; a=b; b=temp;}
```

This also allows you to declare `temp` inside the macro as it has its own local scope if you want, although this restricts the data type.